# How can I increase the size of /tmp on Fedora 25?

Tags: fedora, filesystems, configuration

I'm running Fedora 25 on a VirtualBox VM with 4GB of RAM.  I need to increase the size of the `/tmp` folder, but I do not see any entry in `/etc/fstab` for that folder.  Is is possible to increase the size of `/tmp`?

Comment: Note that `/tmp` is mounted as `tmpfs` on Fedora. `tmpfs` by default makes use  of 50% of your RAM. But you can increase the size with a mount option, either as a percent value or a value in bytes. Now, it depends on why you are trying to increase the amount of `/tmp` or how many space you need. Maybe the source problem is not related to the size of `/tmp`?

Comment: The option to update the Maven remote repository index in IntelliJ IDEA errors out with an out of space message.  I was able to work around it by telling it to use a folder on the hard drive.

Comment: I think in that case, it is better to not use `/tmp` but as you already did use a different location.

Comment: The suggested duplicate should answer the question as stated, but the correct solution to the underlying problem is that given by @Thomas: don’t use `/tmp` for Maven.