# How to increase /tmp folder size manually

Tags: systemd, disk, tmpfs

I have no free space left on 
**/tmp** folder in Fedora 26. That cause several problems.

Folder /tmp takes up all the free RAM:

```
$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.9G   3.9G  12k 100% /tmp
$
```

So, 
**how i can increase size of this folder manually to get more free space without adding more RAM or deleting files from it?**

My question is similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352042/systemd-backed-tmpfs-how-to-specify-tmp-size-manually) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368982/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-tmp-on-fedora-25) but it is different:

- in my question i need to increase size of folder while I've reached maximal size

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
mount -o remount,size=5G /tmp/
```

Comment: Getting "mount: You must specify a filesystem type with -t." in mac.

Comment: Concise and effectual.